# Using ElementTree to parse an XML string with a namespace

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have Googled my pants off to no avail.  What I am trying to do is very simple:  I'd like to access the UniqueID value in the following XML contained in a string using ElementTree.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring

xml_string = """<ListObjectsResponse xmlns='http://www.example.com/dir/'>
        <Item>
                <UniqueID>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789</UniqueID>
        </Item>
</ListObjectsResponse>"""

NS = "http://www.example.com/dir/"

tree = fromstring(xml_string)
```

I know that I should use the `fromstring` method to parse the XML string, but I can't seem to identify how to access the UniqueID.  I'm not certain how to use the `find`, `findall`, or `findtext` methods with respect to the namespace.

Any help is totally appreciated.

Comment: You've googled your pants off? A search for *"ElementTree find namespace"* turned up this as the second hit: ["ElementTree: Working with Namespaces and Qualified Names"](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm)

Comment: I read that entire thing.  Still didn't quite understand it to help with my dilemma I'm afraid.

Comment: @Raj I also rarely understand thoroughly the explanations on the effobot site

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should get you going:

```
>>> tree.findall('*/*')
[<Element '{http://www.example.com/dir/}UniqueID' at 0x10899e450>]
```

This lists all the elements that are two levels below the root of your tree (the UniqueID element, in your case).  You can, alternatively, find only the *first* element at this level, with `tree.find()`.  You can then directly get the text contents of the UniqueID element:

```
>>> unique_id_elmt = tree.find('*/*')  # First (and only) element two levels below the root
>>> unique_id_elmt
<Element '{http://www.example.com/dir/}UniqueID' at 0x105ec9450>
>>> unique_id_elmt.text  # Text contained in UniqueID
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
```

Alternatively, you can directly find some precise element by specifying its [full path](http://effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm):

```
>>> tree.find('{{{0}}}Item/{{{0}}}UniqueID'.format(NS))  # Tags are prefixed with NS
<Element '{http://www.example.com/dir/}UniqueID' at 0x10899ead0>
```

As Tomalak indicated, [Fredrik Lundh's site](http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm) might contain useful information; you want to check how *prefixes* can be handled: there might in fact be a simpler way to handle them than by making explicit the `NS` path in the method above.

Comment: Thanks for the example.  In this case how do I print the actual UniqueID though?

Comment: @Raj: I added code that shows how to get the contents of the UniqueID element.

Answer (score 4):

I know there will be some yells of horror and downvotes for my answer as retaliation, because I use module **re** to analyse an XML string, but note that:

- in the majority of cases , the following solution won't cause any problem
- I wish the downvoters will give examples of cases causing problems with my solution
- I don't parse the string, taking the word 'parse' in the sense of 'obtaining a tree before analysing the tree to find what is searched'; I analyse it: I find directly the whished portion of text where it is

I don't pretend that an XML string must always been analysed with the help of **re**. It is probably in the majority of cases that an XML string must be parsed with a dedicated parser. I only say that in simple cases like this one , in which a simple and fast analyze is possible, it is easier to use the regex tool, which is, by the way, faster.

```
import re

xml_string = """<ListObjectsResponse xmlns='http://www.example.com/dir/'>
        <Item>
                <UniqueID>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789</UniqueID>
        </Item>
</ListObjectsResponse>"""

print xml_string
print '\n=================================\n'

print re.search('<UniqueID>(.+?)</UniqueID>', xml_string, re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

result

```
<ListObjectsResponse xmlns='http://www.example.com/dir/'>
        <Item>
                <UniqueID>abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789</UniqueID>
        </Item>
</ListObjectsResponse>

=================================

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789
```

Comment: +1: This approach is indeed very good in some situations. Is also has the advantage of being very legible (the format of the searched text is very obvious).

Comment: `import reeeeeeeeee`