# XML Parsing w/ Python Element Tree - Namespace sometimes not specified

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to parse a number of xml files that only sometimes have xmlns set. Is there any way to determine whether it's set w/o using the lxml library?

My main issue is when finding elements using find or findall, nothing is returned if the namespace is set since the tag doesn't match. But I can't hardcode the namespace in because sometimes there is no namespace set. I don't really know how to go about this.

Here's a sample of some of my code

```
 tree = ET.parse(xml_file_path)
 root = tree.getroot() #ONIXmessage
 ...
 pids = product.findall("productidentifier")
 ...
```

So my main issue is with the findall() method

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will shortly be having this problem/question too. My thought was: use a wrapper function that first tries to get the elements without the namespace specified, and if that returns `None`, then try with the namespace. If both return None, then the elements were not present. Using both functions (without if-else) works nicely if no default namespace is provided.

If the choice is between the same namespace either being specified or not, then I think ths approach above is okay. If you have multiple-optional-namespaces, it will make your wrapper more complicated but it's a one-time effort.

Would like to see a more elegant solution for this though. Did DanielHaley's answer work?

Related options:

- There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14853417/1431750) answer to specify the namespace in `find`, `findall`, etc.
- Could try [`register_namespace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace) as per the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757887/1431750), which works for writing out.
- [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8511389/1431750) suggests using `*` to find but that's too generic to use to find specific elements.
- [Suppress namespaces altogether](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8116716/1431750)
- If desperate, you can try [using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8518913/1431750)

Comment: Wasn't quite sure how to use Daniel's solution, so I ended up having a wrapper function to add the namespace if present. I grab the namespace using regex. Probably not the most ideal solution. But it seems to work for now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a pain, but you could use [local-name()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-local-name) in your XPath.

For example, instead of:

```
/foo/bar/baz
```

try:

```
/*[local-name()='foo']/*[local-name()='bar']/*[local-name()='baz']
```

Comment: This looks right in principle, but if the OP must use ElementTree, then it won't work (this module only supports [a limited subset of XPath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)). It should work with [lxml](http://lxml.de) which does support full XPath (1.0).